# Gitlab/CI job rule evaluation

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to skip a GitLab ci job based on the results of the previous job, however, as a result, the job never runs. I have the impression that rules are evaluated at the beginning of the Pipeline not at the beginning of the Job. Is there any way to make it work?

```
cache:
  paths:
  - .images

stages:
  - prepare
  - build

dirs:
  stage: prepare
  image:
    name: docker.image.me/run:latest
  script:
    - rm -rf .images/*
    - [ $(($RANDOM % 2)) -eq 1 ] && touch .images/DESKTOP

desktop:
  stage: build
  needs: ["dirs"]
  image:
    name: docker.image.me/run:latest
  rules:
    - exists:
        - .images/DESKTOP
      when: always
  script: 
    - echo "Why is this never launched?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically created jobs could be a solution (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines).

You could create a yml-file with a your "desktop"-job in section "script" in your "dirs"-job if ".images/DESKTOP" is created.
Else your created yml-file should be empty.

The created yml-file can be triggered in a seperat job after "dirs"-job.

I'm using for creating dynamic child pipelines jsonnet (https://jsonnet.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The rules evaluation is happening at the beginning of a Gitlab pipeline

Quoting from Gitlab docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

*`Rules` are `evaluated` when the pipeline is `created`, and evaluated in order until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the configuration.*

Here the problem seems to be with the usage of `exists` keyword

Quoting from Gitlab docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesexists

*Use exists to run a job when certain files exist in the repository*

But here it seems that `.images/DESKTOP` is in Gitlab's runner cache, not in your repository.

```
cache:
  paths:
  - .images
```